# Jodatime - Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, sorting, collections, jodatime, comparator

assume the following java method:

```
private Collection<TimeDTO> sortTimes(Choice choice) {

    final List<TimeDTO> times = new ArrayList<>(timeCache.getAll(choice));

    Collections.sort(times, new Comparator<TimeDTO>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final TimeDTO o1, final TimeDTO o2) {
            if (o1.getTime() == null) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (o2.getTime() == null) {
                return 1;
            }
            return o1.getTime().compareTo(o2.getTime());
        }
    });

    return times;
}
```

The List can contains large amount of items (50000+).
Consider it as a multi-thread environment.
getTime() return "org.joda.time.DateTime".
timeCache can change on other threads.

But sometimes still got:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:899) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:516) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:439) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1464) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:177) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at ****.ServiceImpl.sortTimes(ServiceImpl.java:100)
```

What can be the problem? Any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: IMHO you don't properly account for the case where both `o1.getTime()` and `o2.getTime()` return null. Your comparator should return 0 for that special case.

Comment: It's easier (and more self-evidently correct) to use `Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(TimeDTO::getTime))`

Comment: In that case of Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(TimeDTO::getTime))
I got NullpointerException

Comment: Thanks @ThomasKläger I give it a try. I cannot reproduce the case in test... it appears only on production environment.

Comment: @RómeóNagy `Comparator.comparing(TimeDTO::getTime, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())`, or similar then.

Comment: @AndyTurner . Yes, it is working now. Thank you. Then I will try this first, it is a  compact and should be good solution.

Comment: @RómeóNagy If you solved your problem, draft, post, and accept an Answer to your own Question.